# MAUI iOS saving Preferences in Debug build, but not in release build deployed to app store

Tags: ios, maui, release, preferences

When I build my app in VS 2022 on Mac or Windows in Debug configuration, preferences save and read fine. However, once I build the app in Release configuration and deploy it to the app store to be tested on TestFlight the Preferences no longer save/read.

Note: When I build and publish an Android release version, the preferences save/read correctly.

Here are the save and read methods:

```cs
public void CreateItem(string key, dynamic value) {
    Preferences.Default.Set(key, value);
}

public string GetString(string key) {
    String contents = null;

    try {
        contents = Preferences.Get(key, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return contents;
}
```

**Update** I built the app in DEBUG and deployed it to my phone in these 2 ways with different results:

1. Using the app's "Developer Cert" and "Developer Provisioning Profile", which results in save/read for Preferences working.
2. Using the app's "Distribution Cert" and "Distribution Provisioning Profile", which results in save/read for Preferences *NOT* working.

Comment: If you do Release build, and test it from Visual Studio, *to the same device or emulator you tested Debug build,* do Preferences work? [To determine whether there is something different about a deployed app, or whether it is Release build itself that has the issue.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks for the input! I managed to build and deploy to my device but needed to changing my signing cert to "Developer (Automatic)" and provisioning profile to "Automatic". The issue does remain and preferences are not saving/reading. Based on some other things I was reading today it may have to do with the Preferences object not instantiating or with how the build is compressing the libraries. I'm going to tinker with the build options and see what I can find out.

Comment: Did you get any error info since you use try catch?

Comment: Never do this: `catch (Exception ex) { }`. That throws away the error message and continues as if nothing went wrong. But something did go wrong; you're just not able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wasn't able to resolve the issue with saving to Preferences, nor was I able to get a clear error message since it was a Release build and can't be connected to VS for debugging where I could see my console print statements in my try/catch blocks. I suppose a workaround to that would be to try and print those messages in a alert like so:
`DisplayAlert("Alert", "<error message body here>", "OK");`

I did however find a profitable solution which was to save my JSON objects and strings to files like so:

```
public class LocalStorageService {
    private string documentsFolder;

    public LocalStorageService() {
        this.documentsFolder = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
    }

    public string ReadTextFile(string fileName) {
        string data = null;

        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, $"{fileName}.json");

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                data = File.ReadAllText(path);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in LocalStorageService::ReadTextFile(): {ex.Message}");
    }

        return data;
    }


    public void WriteToFile(string fileName, string json) {
        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, $"{fileName}.json");
            File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in LocalStorageService::WriteToFile(): {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I call the save and read like this:

```
//write
localStorageService.WriteToFile(LocalStorageItemNames.USER_PROFILE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profileModel)

//read
string model = localStorageService.ReadTextFile(LocalStorageItemNames.USER_METAS);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) {
    profileModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileModel>(model);
}
```

Comment: Maui Preferences has [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=macios#limitations). I am not sure if you store too large amounts of text.